# JQuery to regular JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar

For learning purposes I'm converting this scrollbar into regular JavaScript. I'm simply writing JQuery out of the script (JQuery is great, but I wish to learn raw JavaScript before using JQuery).

Here's the scrollbar code:

http://jsfiddle.net/PVZB8/139/

I don't understand how to turn the last few lines into regular JavaScript:

```
$('#chatlist').slimscroll({
    color: '#000',
    size: '8px',
    width: '150px',
    height: '250px'                  
});
```

I would assume that $('#chatlist') is equal to document.getElementById('chatlist') but of course this fails because a div element does not have a method named 'slimscroll'...

I sort of understand what these lines of code does (creating a new instance of slimscroll and passing some options).

How would these lines look if we took out JQuery? How would the whole script look without using JQuery?

(I understand that not all aspects of the script will work in a similar way without JQuery, like the fade functionality for instance)

Comment: The settings is just a object. If i was you I would try to write a very basic jQuery plugin, this is easy and you will understand some new things!

Answer (score 6):

> I don't understand how to turn the last few lines into regular JavaScript:

The code calls the function stored in `$.fn.slimscroll` with `this` bound to the jQuery object containing the element with the id `chatlist` and passes an object containing the values you specified to that function.

> How would the whole script look without using JQuery?

Nobody here is going to convert the whole script to plain JavaScript for you. I also wouldn't suggest you to do it - it will be a shitload of work since you lose all the nice DOM traversal functions etc.